# How to selecting value from another data extension in select statement in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automation, database

I have a DE extension where I have saved 1 record by querying:

```
Select top 1
JobID,
EmailName,
CreatedDate,
JobType,
JobStatus
from _job
```

Output is saved in data extension: **DataView_Job_DE**

Now, I am writing another query where I want to get value from DataView_Job_DE in my select statement like this:

```
SELECT
CustomerID,
CustomerEmail,
'Orange' as FavColor,
(SELECT TOP 1 EmailName FROM ENT.DataView_Job_DE) AS EmailName
FROM Customer_DE
```

**The above query is throwing an error:**

```
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax.
```

How can I resolve this error? Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there is a more direct way to this - but to stick with your approach to first have one record isolated, here's how it could be achieved.

number your first query's result:

```
Select top 1
JobID
,EmailName
,CreatedDate
,JobType
,JobStatus
,Row_Number() OVER (Partition by jobid ORDER BY Jobid) as rowNumber
from _job
```

...returning something like this to your DataView_Job_DE (which needs an extra field), which still has one record, but the record is numbered:

`JobID` `EmailName` `CreatedDate` `JobType` `JobStatus` `rowNumber`

`12345 / Test / Nov 22 2022 3:22AM / MULTIPLE_SEND / New / 1`

Then select from your customers, joining the other table to get the row with  rowNumber being 1.

```
SELECT
CustomerId, 
'Orange' as FavColor,
pre.EmailName AS EmailName
FROM Customer_DE c

INNER JOIN 

[result of first Query] pre
on pre.rowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Hi @Jonas Lamberty the INNER JOIN will have just the table name, right? INNER JOIN ON DataView_Job_DE on pre.rowNumber = 1? Sorry, I am not following that is [result of first Query] ?

Comment: Replace `[result of first Query]` with the data extension name of the first query's target DE. You can omit the brackets, unless you use spaces in your DE Name ;)

Comment: Thank you, I will mark this as closed / answers. Based on learning from this approach, I have posted another question, i would really appreciate if you could please help / guide? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/403185/how-to-get-records-from-sendable-audience-who-did-not-make-it-to-sent-log-witho